# What is the best removable insulation material?

Tags: repair, insulation, walls, crack

There is a crack in a wall that I would like to fill with some removable insulation.

It must be removable, as such it should just be a temporary solution.

I know of rockwool and glasswool, but don't know which is best, or if there exist other types.

Which should I get and stump the crack with?

Comment: What sort of wall (material, interior/exterior)? Why are you trying to stuff it with insulation instead of repairing the crack? How big is the crack? Are you trying to insulate for heat, sound or visual? A picture of the crack may help

Comment: Additionally, what caused the crack? How long is "temporary"?

Comment: there really isn't a best insulation for crack repair.

Comment: Blown-in insulation is technically removable if you have a shopvac! :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [Backer Rod](http://www.bestmaterials.com/Backer_Rod.aspx) to fill in the crack if it is not too wide.  Backer rod is an easy to compress rope-like celled foam and should be easy to remove at a later date.  It is mainly used to fill deep cracks before caulking to give support to the caulk.

Backer rod comes in a variety of diameters and should be able to be found at your local building supply store.

[image]